# Serializer/deserializer generator for Scala

Tags: json, scala, serialization

I'm writing my first Scala application and I need to (de)serialize objects to/from JSON.

I'm used to OCaml where I heavily use [atdgen](http://mylifelabs.github.io/atdgen-tutorial.html) for this kind of task. It's a code generator that reads my types and generates the serialization & deserialization code for me.

So serializing a value can be as straightforward as (OCaml code):

```
MyTypeModule.Json.to_string my_value
```

Is there any tool of this kind for Scala?

Comment: Try spray-json `resolvers += "spray" at "http://repo.spray.io/"`

`libraryDependencies += "io.spray" %%  "spray-json" % "1.2.6"`